# Hibernate group by of a parent table

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two domain as follows

```
WishList{
  int id;
  @ManyToOne
  Item item;
}

Item{
 int id;
 int productCategory;
 String productName;
}
```

Now Suppose I have product

```
(1,1,Mobile )
(2,2,Microwave)
(3,3,flashDrive)
(4,1, Monitor)
```

Now How do I group by query in `WishList` so that I get

```
(1,1,Mobile )
(4,1, Monitor)
(2,2,Microwave)
(3,3,flashDrive)
```

I am using `Hibernate Criteria`

How to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using hibernate [`Criteria`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) you can create [`alias`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) for `Item` like

```
Criteria criteria = hibernetSession.createCriteria(WishList.class);
criteria.createAlias("item", "itemAlias")
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("id"),"id")
.add(Projections.property("itemAlias.id"),"itemAlias.id")
.add(Projections.property("itemAlias.productCategory"),"itemAlias.productCategory")
.add(Projections.property("itemAlias.productName"),"itemAlias.productName")
.add(Projections.groupProperty("itemAlias.productName")))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(WishList.class));
List<WishList> itemList = criteria.list();
```

and use [`Projections`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) for [`grouping`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection)

Comment: i am getting syntax error >>>>> `The method add(Criterion) in the type Criteria is not applicable for the arguments (PropertyProjection)`

Comment: another error after using updated code `The method setResultTransformer(ResultTransformer) is undefined for the type ProjectionList`

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have eclipse with me right now there was bracket misplaced check now! I hope you basically understood the direction I am trying to point.